Most Economical Way to Add Kitchen Cabinets to the Ceiling, with Glass/Windows?
[I just closed on my first home! At some point, I want to pop off the existing trim and add cabinets on top of my existing kitchen cabinets, in order to “extend” them all the way to the ceiling. I love how it makes a space feel taller and larger, adds storage (even if I may rarely “use” it and will need a ladder when I do), and that dust won’t accumulate there since it’s not just an empty space anymore.
I specifically would like cabinets that have the glass/windows (at least some of them, still debating if I want it to be all of them) and preferably added lights inside. Please see the photo for a reference of what I’m going for (the upper cabinets specifically).
What would be the most economical way to accomplish this? Are there any sites I may be able to order these kind of cabinets from and DIY this?
Thank you in advance for all advice and tips! :)

there are sites where you can order these

contact the cabinet manufacturer and see if they make them

Are you tall enough to reach them?  They might look nice but having to use a step every time you want something from them, gets old fast.

@crip659 OP mentioned they may rarely be used and will need a ladder when they are.

OP, I assume this is some kind of stock photo or a Pinterest type photo.  Do you know how much height you have to deal with in your own kitchen?

@Huesmann yes, that is just the inspiration photo. In my own kitchen the ceiling is about 8 feet high I believe; its a decrease from the ceiling of the attached great room, where the ceiling peak is about 12 feet high.

@Mia I meant, how much space do you have between the current cabinets' top and the ceiling?

@Huesmann sorry haha. I actually am not sure yet. But I asked my builder's cabinet guy for a quote, and he told me 3350. That's just for materials and install of the upper cabinets; no lighting/electrical work.

What you are wanting are cabinets with glass doors. (Not windows)
There are a number of manufacturers of these cabinets. They can be purchased through the big box stores and cabinet distributors. There are online cabinet distributors as well.
If you are not familiar with installing cabinets, I would avoid online sellers and use the services of the local stores. They will send an individual to measure your space to be sure the cabinets will be able to fit. They will also tell you if you need fill strips and go over trim options. Ask the store if they have a certified kitchen and bath designer. They are trained and experienced in getting cabinets to work correctly.  (they know when there is a need to have space to open a door and how much offset a cabinet needs, etc.)  Then you will get the best results.
Installing is straight forward. Screw through the back into studs in the wall. Screw adjacent cabinets together. Again if you are not familiar, you may want a professional to do this, or hire a handyman.
